# How to specify number of digits in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to specify number of digits in regexp pattern for awk

I have a file:

```
 #test 34
 # test 34
 #test34
 # test 3a4
 #blahtest 34
 #test yes
```

I need to return results with field value like number (**34**) or word(**yes**).

**3a4** it's incorrect value,

**blahtest** and **test34** it's incorrect field name

One more example is */etc/ssh/sshd_config*. I'd like to find in this file the line with parameter and it's value. I don't know this value before I find line with this parameter. Then I need to change this value to another. Example `#Port 22 -> #Port <my_value>`
**My logic**
See the code below. 
**function get_fielad_value()** has two arguments: $1 - Field name $2 - path to file in which to find. This function returns field value. I used awk to find line matched to pattern. So what if there is line having incorrect field value? I need to correct my pattern. awk should search notmatching not to only field name but field values too. It can be numbers or words. In light of the above I should use:

```
awk '/^# *'"$some_str"' +([[:digit:]]{1,5}|[[:alpha:]]*) {print;exit;}'
```

`[[:digit:]]{1,5}|[[:alpha:]]*` means that line to find can contain five-digit (or less) number OR letters 
This is my bash script. Hope it will make my question clearer.

```
#!/bin/bash

#comment string
comment() {
    #if str1=$(awk '/^'"$1"'')
    sed -i "/^$1/ c# $1" $2
}

#uncomment string
uncomment() {

    if str1=$(awk '/^# *'"$1"' +/ {gsub(/^#|^# +/,""); print; exit;}' $2)
    then
        sed -i "s/^#\+ *$str1/$str1/" $2
    fi
}

#get field value
get_field_value() {
    FIELD_VALUE=$(awk '/^# *'"$1"' +/ {gsub(/^#|^# +/,""); print $2;exit;}' $2)
}

#set field
set_field_value(){
    get_field_value $1 $2

}

#replace field
replace_field(){
    sed "s/$1/$2/g"
}

set_field_value test test 777
uncomment test test
```

Comment: Are those 1,2,3... etc at the start of each line present in your actual file, or are you trying to indicate line numbers?

Comment: And what does *doesn't work at all* mean? No results, too many results, what?

Comment: I think it would be better if you describe your problem by: I have an input file, looks like .... ,I want to get .... And the logic is ....

Comment: @Shawn 1,2,3 it's just an example. I'd like to use this function to find field in a file and change it's value. For example in /etc/ssh/sshd_config #Port 22 I want to uncomment and change value from 22 to otherone. The command I've written gives no result

Comment: Are those numbers in your file or aren't they? The overly-literal answers you're getting are assuming they are but your RE suggests they aren't because of the `^#` part...

Comment: And that description of what you want doesn't match up with your question at all. You should edit it and clarify things.

Comment: @Kent I'll try but my English is poor enough=) Like I said I want to write a function based on awk to find commented(#)/uncommented lines in file by field name and change it's value. I'd like to filter wrong values like 3a4 in my example above. Field values can be numbers or yes/no. My logic is to find #<spaces/no space><Field name><spaces><5 sign number or word>

Comment: @Shawn I edited my post. Please excuse me. My English is awful.

Comment: @TmYAG, IMHO, you could mention 3 simple things. 1- sample of input(already there). 2- sample of output(with logic how to get it). 3- what you tried(you have already mentioned), always these 3 things are needed on SO :)

Comment: I'm a little confused, so you want to change all the values from `cat test | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'` which 34, test, , test, 34, yes

Comment: @Benbentwo I want to have such functional to change value of one field. Final target is to find line matched to pattern and change the value. If you look at comments below you'll see that tripleee understands me. But I cant understand why using [[:digit:]]{1,5} pattern doesn't properly work for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions. Try this:

```
awk '{if ($1 == 1 || $1 == 2 || $1 == 6) print $0}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
awk -v keyname="$somestring" '$0 ~ "^ *# *" keyname " +([[:digit:]]{1,5}|[[:alpha:]]+)($|[[:space:]] )"'
```

With `somestring="test"` it will return these lines from your sample:

```
 #test 34
 # test 34
 #test yes
```

Your regex would not allow spaces before `#` but I tweaked the regex to allow that, and also to restrict the context after the final digit/alpha group (otherwise it would just look at an alpha string and stop matching but accept it as soon as it saw a digit after a letter in the last field).

For some really old Awk implementations, try

```
awk -v keyname="$somestring" '$0 ~ "^ *# *" keyname " +([0-9]([0-9]([0-9]([0-9][0-9]?)?)?)?|[A-Za-z]+)($|[ \t])"'
```

Comment: This does not print `#test34`, your prose description reads vaguely like you would want that too, but I can't see how that sits with the rest of the question as I understand it.

Comment: #test34 it's incorrect field in my meaning. Problem is that pattern with [[:digit:]]{1,5} not working for me. I can't understand why

Comment: So then this solution is correct? Can you comment on whether I managed to guess what you actually are trying to do?

Comment: Yes! You were right. I try to find out why your solution doesn't properly work for me

Comment: Maybe you're using an old version of awk that doesn't support character classes or RE intervals, e.g. nawk.

Comment: @EdMorton it seems You're right. Is there any solution? awk -W version gives: mawk 1.3.3

Comment: You can replace character classes with character ranges so `[[:digit:]]` -> `[0-9]` and `[[:alpha:]]` -> `[a-zA-Z]` in most English-speaking locales but if RE intervals are also not supported then you need a different approach, e.g. `{n=sub(/[0-9]+/,"&")} n>=1 && n<=5` instead of `/[0-9]{1,5}/` (use with caution as it's not exactly equivalent) or `[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?` or similar.